# Can't add Team ID in Firebase Project settings

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to add dynamic links to my app and I am following this guide:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFPo296OQqk

At around 3:20 he explains how to add team ID in the project settings but for me this option simply isn't there. I have checked all my projects and none of them has this option in project settings. This is a problem since dynamic links does not work without that added since I've seen people around with similar problem as me (that was solved by adding the Team ID they had forgot).

Is there any solution to this?

I'm working on a iOS project and my location is Sweden if that somehow matters.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I resolved this by instead adding the team ID to the **App ID Prefix** field.

Seems to be working in the exact same way.

Answer (score 73):

In my case, it tried one more time and Team ID automaticaly detected, just fill Key ID and upload .p8 file

Comment: Yes, I have the error for first time click and it is ok without change anything for second click

Comment: This worked for me as well. TeamID is available in your [membership](https://developer.apple.com/account/#/membership/) area in apple's account.

Comment: In my case, I did nothing else than just clicking on the "Send" button one more time and it worked (without the need to re-upload the file...) Strange !

Answer (score 38):

Click on **upload** again, it will just take it. Maybe some glitch.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, Prefix is the Team ID. You can go to your Apple Developer page, Keys, then choose the app and see the prefix.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In my case, it tried one more time and it just worked without any changes

Answer (score 4):

You can find your team ID here:

https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list

click on your app identifier, the team ID will be at the top of the page just above the Bundle ID

[image: Team ID location]

Answer (score 2):

App ID Prefix field changed to Team ID now. In my case only setting Team ID did not work.

I found push notification certificates are not set to the App ID and fixing it resolved this issue.